# Firebase Authentication won't show anything

Tags: ios, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

When tapping on login the firebase default screen appears but nothing else. This is my code, which is from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=brpt9Thi6GU&t=425s). I can't seem to resolve this. I skipped the part to verify that the link between my app and the firebase is properly set up as shown in the tutorial because it seems like google has removed it.. Could this be the problem? How can I verify that everything is set up fine? Besides that there should not **not** be anything, right?

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseUI

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Create the default auth UI object
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

        guard authUI != nil else {
            // Log error
            return
        }

        // Set ourselves as delegate
        authUI?.delegate = self

        // Get a reference to the auth View Controller
        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()

        // Show vc
        present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension UIViewController: FUIAuthDelegate {
    public func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            // log
            return
        }

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "UITabBarController", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Console:

```
2019-08-20 11:18:34.261429+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542063]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2019-08-20 11:18:34.401130+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542063] 6.6.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60100000 started
2019-08-20 11:18:34.401729+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542063] 6.6.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see url)
2019-08-20 11:18:49.787968+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542350] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fae63e08850] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-20 11:18:49.788281+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542350] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x7fae63e08850] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-20 11:18:49.788763+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542350] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-20 11:18:49.788911+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542350] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-20 11:18:49.790706+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542350] 6.6.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023130] Configuration not found. Using default configuration
2019-08-20 11:18:49.876512+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542349] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fae63f05270] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-20 11:18:49.876663+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542349] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fae63f05270] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-08-20 11:18:49.876928+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542349] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-08-20 11:18:49.877067+0200 WGdotorg[9434:542349] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
```

[image: default screen]

Comment: can you post debug log?

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper added it

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper actually, that is not the Debugger Output. There is no Debugger Output, this is the Target Output..

Comment: it seems firebug is working. you have double-checked the AppDelegate and set throw the code